# How does an os know an application was downloaded from the web?

Tags: macos, security, metadata

I download a compressed tar file; I uncompress it; I run `make`, compiling a large number of object files that are then linked to make an executable, which is embedded in a (Mac OS X) application.

I run the application, and the OS asks me, So-and-so is an application downloaded from the web; do you really want to run it?

How does the OS know?

Comment: I can't give you a definitive answer for every OS so I won't post this as an answer. I can tell you that for windows, when the file is being downloaded the OS sets a flag in an Alternate Data Stream on the file. I suspect that the other OS's do something similar.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is **Gatekeeper**

**The message that you are seeing is a warning from Gatekeeper**

Gatekeeper is a security feature in OS X that builds on OS X's existing malware checks to help protect your Mac from malware and misbehaving apps downloaded from the Internet.

> For apps that are downloaded from places other than the Mac App Store,
>   developers can get a unique Developer ID from Apple and use it to
>   digitally sign their apps.The Developer ID allows Gatekeeper to block
>   apps created by malware developers and verify that apps haven't been
>   tampered with since they were signed. If an app was developed by an
>   unknown developer—one with no Developer ID—or tampered with,
>   Gatekeeper can block the app from being installed.

Source : https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT202491